# How to get the value of an Entry created in a def?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm working on a project and i would like to get the Value of an Entry created in a def (turned on by a button on Tkinter)

So I have my main tkinter menu, with a button which will call the def "panier".
The def "panier" is creating the Entry "value" and another button to call a second def "calcul".
The second def "calcul" will do things with the value of Entry...
But then, in the def "calcul", when i'm trying to do value.get() it tells "NameError: name 'value' is not defined"

Here is the code, btw the Entry must be created by the def...

```
from tkinter import *

def panier():
    value=Entry(test)
    value.pack()
    t2=Button(test,text="Validate",command=calcul)
    t2.pack()

def calcul(value):
    a=value.get()
    #here will be the different calculations I'll do

test=Tk()

t1=Button(test,text="Button",command=panier)
t1.pack()

test.mainloop()
```

Appreciate every feedback :)

Comment: `t2=Button(test,text="Validate",command=calcul)` -> `t2=Button(test,text="Validate",command=lambda :calcul(value))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the variable global like this:

```py
from tkinter import *

def panier():
    global value
    value = Entry(test)
    value.pack()
    t2 = Button(test, text="Validate", command=calcul)
    t2.pack()

def calcul():
    a = value.get()
    print(a)
    #here will be the different calculations I'll do

test = Tk()

t1 = Button(test, text="Button", command=panier)
t1.pack()

test.mainloop()
```

The `global value` line makes the variable global so you can use it anywhere in your program.

You can also pass in the variable as an argument like what @JacksonPro suggested
`t2 = Button(test, text="Validate", command=lambda: calcul(value))`

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it. Globally create a collection (list or dictionary) to hold a reference to the Entry. When you create the Entry, add it to the collection. I made it with either a list or dictionary for holding the references, so toggle the commented variations in all three places to try it both ways.

```
import tkinter as tk

def panier():
    for item in ('value', ):
        ent = tk.Entry(test)

        collection.append(ent)
        # collection[item] = ent

        ent.pack()
    
    t2 = tk.Button(test,text="Validate",command=calcul)
    t2.pack()


def calcul():

    a = collection[0].get()
    # a = collection['value'].get()

    print(a)

collection = []
# collection = {}

test = tk.Tk()

t1 = tk.Button(test, text="Button", command=panier)
t1.pack()

test.mainloop()
```